# Sequential execution of threads using synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a snippet of code that creates 3 threads and expect them to print sequentially using synchronized block on the integer object. But apparently I am getting deadlock sometimes. See below:

```
public class SequentialExecution implements Runnable {

    private Integer i = 1;

    public void run() {

        String tmp = Thread.currentThread().getName();

        if (tmp.equals("first")) {
            synchronized(i) {
                first();
                i = 2;
            }
        } else if (tmp.equals("second")) {
            while (i != 2);
            synchronized(i) {
                second();
                i = 3;
            }
        } else {
            while (i != 3);
            synchronized(i) {
                third();
            }
        }

    }

    public void first() {
        System.out.println("first " + i);
    }

    public void second() {
        System.out.println("second " + i);
    }

    public void third() {
        System.out.println("third " + i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create 3 threads and call first(), second() and third() sequentially
        SequentialExecution se = new SequentialExecution();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(se, "first");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(se, "second");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(se, "third");

        t3.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.start();

    }

}
```

The result I am expecting(and sometimes getting) is:

```
first 1
second 2
third 3
```

One sample result I am getting with deadlock(and eclipse hangs) is:

```
first 1
second 2
```

Anyone know why this is not working? I know I can use locks but I just don't know why using synchronized block is not working.

Comment: 1) what is your main method.  2) why do you reset the variable `i`?  I think that is your problem.  When you say `i = 2` it's now a different object and thus should require a different lock.

Comment: @Jared So a follow up question would be: would it work if I use i++ in this case?

Comment: I'm still not totally sure what the problem is--I'm trying to reproduce it (I've seen that you get a hang up--although now I'm not getting a hang-up).  `i++` wouldn't change the fact that you are reassignging the pointer `i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare `i` to be `volatile`: `private volatile Integer i = 1;`. This warns the compiler that it must not apply certain optimizations to `i`. It must be read from memory each time it is referenced in case another thread has changed it.

I also agree with the recommendation in user3582926's answer to synchronize on `this` rather than `i`, because the object referenced by `i` changes as the program runs. It is neither necessary nor sufficient to make the program work, but it does make it a better, clearer program.

I have tested each change by changing the main method to:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // create 3 threads and call first(), second() and third() sequentially
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      SequentialExecution se = new SequentialExecution();
      Thread t1 = new Thread(se, "first");
      Thread t2 = new Thread(se, "second");
      Thread t3 = new Thread(se, "third");

      t3.start();
      t2.start();
      t1.start();
      t1.join();
      t2.join();
      t3.join();
    }

  }
```

There is no deadlock. There is a memory order issue.

The while loops in the second and third threads are outside any synchronized block. There is nothing telling the compiler and JVM that those threads cannot keep `i`, or the object to which it points, in a register or cache during the loop. The effect is that, depending on timing, one of those threads may get stuck looping looking at a value that is not going to change.

One way to solve the problem is to mark `i` volatile. That warns the compiler that it is being used for inter-thread communication, and each thread needs to watch for changes in memory contents whenever `i` changes.

In order to solve it entirely using synchronization, you need to check the value of the Integer referenced by `i` inside a block that is synchronized on a single, specific object. `i` is no good for that, because it changes due to boxing/unboxing conversion. It might as well be a simple `int`.

The synchronized blocks cannot wrap the while loops, because that really would lead to deadlock. Instead, the synchronized block has to be inside the loop. If the updates to `i` are synchronized on the same object, that will force the updates to be visible to the tests inside the while loops.

These considerations lead to the following synchronization-based version. I am using a main method that does 1000 runs, and will itself hang if any thread in any of those runs hangs.

```
public class SequentialExecution implements Runnable {

  private int i = 1;

  public void run() {

    String tmp = Thread.currentThread().getName();

    if (tmp.equals("first")) {
      synchronized (this) {
        first();
        i = 2;
      }
    } else if (tmp.equals("second")) {
      while (true) {
        synchronized (this) {
          if (i == 2) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      synchronized (this) {
        second();
        i = 3;
      }
    } else {
      while (true) {
        synchronized (this) {
          if (i == 3) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      synchronized (this) {
        third();
      }
    }

  }

  public void first() {
    System.out.println("first " + i);
  }

  public void second() {
    System.out.println("second " + i);
  }

  public void third() {
    System.out.println("third " + i);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // create 3 threads and call first(), second() and third() sequentially
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      SequentialExecution se = new SequentialExecution();
      Thread t1 = new Thread(se, "first");
      Thread t2 = new Thread(se, "second");
      Thread t3 = new Thread(se, "third");

      t3.start();
      t2.start();
      t1.start();
      t1.join();
      t2.join();
      t3.join();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: @TheLostMind Can you explain why this is not working? It appears to work for me.

Comment: @hashsort -  Hadn't added the *volatile* modifier.. My bad.. This code works.. Still, you are using both *busy-wait* and *synchronization*. `while (i != 2);
            synchronized(i) {` . recheck your code /design.

Comment: I would still like to see an actual explanation of the deadlock.  I am having trouble understanding it.  It would seem to me that somehow there is an un-atomic operation with setting `i = 2` (for instance).  Where somehow the second thread sees that `i == 2` and thus exits its loop but then it doesn't enter its `synchronized` block because the first thread hasn't released the initial object `i = 1` (but at this point `i` should be a different object so synchronization shouldn't even be an issue!).

Comment: @Jared I've added an explanation. The basic issue is memory order, or rather lack of memory order. In the original program there is nothing forcing the compiler and JVM to reload `i` in the while loops that are waiting for it to change - they can go on running for ever with `i` equal to 1 in a register or cache.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Thanks for the additional explanation.  It is informative about when _and_ why `volatile` is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to be using `synchronized(this)` instead of `synchronized(i)`.

Comment: It would be a better program with this change. However, I tested it, and this change is not sufficient to make the program work. Without the `volatile` keyword a thread can go on working with an old Integer instance without notices that the variable has changed. With the `volatile` keyword, each thread sees each change in `i`, and at any given stage they are all synchronizing on the same variable.